# Erro do Cannot GET /get

Tags: javascript, get, inicialização, princípios-de-programação, const

MINHACRUD


    
       form{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        word-break: normal;
       }

```
<form action="get">
   <div>
    <p>seu nome:</p>
    <input type="text" name="" id="nome">
   </div>
   <div>
    <p>seu email:</p>
    <input type="email" name="" id="email"><br>
   </div><br>
   <button onclick="novosusarios()">Cadastrar</button>
</form>

   
<div id="usuarios">

</div>
<script>
  const nome = document.getElementById('nome')
  const email = document.getElementById('email')

  const resultado = document.getElementById('usuarios')

   function cadastrar(nome,email){
       const usuariosNovos = document.createElement('div')
       usuariosNovos.innerHTML = `
            <p>${nome}</p>
            <p>${email}</p>
            <button onclick = "Deletar()">delete</button>
            <button onclick = "Adcionar()">adicionar</button>
       `
       return usuariosNovos
   }
   resultado.innerHTML(cadastrar(nome, email));

</script>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta convertendo o código em um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.